# how do i move the cursor on pressing enter from a textbox on a form to that on it's subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

on pessing enter the cursor moves to other textboxes in the form.

i want it to jump to that field on the subform first. how can i go about it

Comment: What do you mean by "that field on the subform" - why would the same field be on main and sub form? Maybe in textbox AfterUpdate event: `Me.subformcontainername.Form.textboxname.SetFocus`.

Answer (score 1):

You first have to move the focus to the subform, then to the textbox on this, thus *two* steps:

```vb
Me!NameOfYourSubformControl.SetFocus
Me!NameOfYourSubformControl.Form!YourTextbox.SetFocus
```